# Ограничить кол-во элементов в цикле

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Помогите пожалуйста ограничить вывод количества элементов в списке до двух

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q209o0gm/17/)

html:

```
<div ng-app="newsFeed">
  <div ng-controller="newsFeedController">
    <ul class="news_list">
      <li ng-repeat="newsItem in news | limitTo:2">
        <div class="title">{{ newsItem.title }}</div>
      </li>
    </ul> 
  </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
var newsFeed = angular.module('newsFeed', []);

newsFeed.factory('initDataService', function(){
    return{
        initData:{
            "values":{
                "id1": {"title":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit.", "poster": "1.jpg", "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adssumenda expedita molestias tenetur, quam nostrum nisi praesentium necessitatibus doloribus!"},
                "id2": {"title":"Nobis delectus deleniti, amet.", "poster": "2.jpg", "description": "Fuga, porro, nemo. Ut, nisi reicieum tempore."},
                "id3": {"title":"Sequi alias, cur! Sapiente sit esse ipsa! Doloremque voluptates pariatur non eaque laborum."},
                "id4": {"title":"Odit tempora temporicia eius voluptates magnam quam similique, accusantium consequatur."},
                "id5": {"title":"Recusandae possimus qui tempore."},
                "id6": {"title":"Placeat enim, facilis molestiae.", "poster": "6.jpg", "description": "Consectetur aperiam nam esse earum, repudiandae, ta impedit! Illum, assumenda?"},
            }
        }
    };
})

var newsFeedModule = angular.module('newsFeed');

newsFeedModule.controller('newsFeedController', function($scope, initDataService) {
    $scope.posterWidth = 100;
    $scope.posterHeight = 60;

    $scope.news = initDataService.initData.values;
});
```

Comment: и в чем проблема? А, увидел, - поменять _"values"_ на массив и все заработает

Comment: так? https://jsfiddle.net/q209o0gm/19/ 
не заработало

Comment: естественно не заработает, синтаксическая ошибка же

Comment: ааа.. ну это все данные нужно перелопатить. а если их миллион строк будет?

Comment: а они вручную разве собираются?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Фильтр `limitTo` работает только с массивами. Так как в данном случае используется объект - он его же и возвращает.

Решение может быть множество: от фильтрации в контроллере перед выводом так как нужно, до написания собственного фильтра.

Фильтр может выглядеть так:

```
filter('objectProplimitTo', function() {
  return function(obj, count) {
    var res = [];
    for (var p in obj) {
      if (res.length == count) return res;
      res.push(obj[p]);
    }
  }
  return res;
})
```

Рабочий пример:

```js
var newsFeed = angular.module('newsFeed', []);

newsFeed.factory('initDataService', function() {
  return {
    initData: {
      "values": {
        "id1": {
          "title": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit.",
          "poster": "1.jpg",
          "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adssumenda expedita molestias tenetur, quam nostrum nisi praesentium necessitatibus doloribus!"
        },
        "id2": {
          "title": "Nobis delectus deleniti, amet.",
          "poster": "2.jpg",
          "description": "Fuga, porro, nemo. Ut, nisi reicieum tempore."
        },
        "id3": {
          "title": "Sequi alias, cur! Sapiente sit esse ipsa! Doloremque voluptates pariatur non eaque laborum."
        },
        "id4": {
          "title": "Odit tempora temporicia eius voluptates magnam quam similique, accusantium consequatur."
        },
        "id5": {
          "title": "Recusandae possimus qui tempore."
        },
        "id6": {
          "title": "Placeat enim, facilis molestiae.",
          "poster": "6.jpg",
          "description": "Consectetur aperiam nam esse earum, repudiandae, ta impedit! Illum, assumenda?"
        },
      }
    }
  };
})

var newsFeedModule = angular.module('newsFeed');

newsFeedModule.controller('newsFeedController', function($scope, initDataService) {
  $scope.posterWidth = 100;
  $scope.posterHeight = 60;

  $scope.news = initDataService.initData.values;
}).filter('objectProplimitTo', function() {
  return function(obj, count) {
    var res = [];
    for (var p in obj) {
      if (res.length == count) return res;
      res.push(obj[p]);
    }
  }
  return res;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="newsFeed">
  <div ng-controller="newsFeedController">
    <ul class="news_list">
      <li ng-repeat="newsItem in news | objectProplimitTo:2">
        <div class="title">{{ newsItem.title }}</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Не самое лучшее решение, но будет работать как надо:

```
$scope.news=[
    {"title":initDataService.initData.values[0].title},
    {"title":initDataService.initData.values[1].title}
];
```

Если надо больше, то циклом по `initDataService.initData.values` пройдись.

На мой взгляд, самым лучшим будет создать метод в твоем сервисе который возвращает 2 элемента, и с сервера подтягивать лишь 2.